# Team foundation CI build watching specific branch

Tags: tfs, build-automation, tfsbuild

How can I setup an automated TFS build which would fire up only when check-in occurs in a specific branch of the project as opposed to on every single check-in across the team project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In the Team Explorer there should be a folder "Builds" for your team project.
- Right click, then choose "New build definition" from the context menu.
- Set the trigger to whatever you like, e.g. gated checkin.
- On the "Workspace" tab you can now choose for which workspace the build applies. **Here you can choose the server path of a specific branch**. Set this to the server path(s) you want the build to trigger on.
- On the process tab you can choose which solution to build.

Hope that helps.